# vb.net: Jump out of exceptioned function

Tags: vb.net

I am just reworking my VB6 in .NET.

I have a function that is called NonNullString(byval uAny As Object) As String

In VB6 I worked with a sqlite wrapper, and a recordset's member could be accessed by using

```
Dim sString$
sString = r("somefield")
```

(without ".Value")

I have really many of these fields, and I changed most of them to ".Value", but for some I forgot it.

An exception is therefore raised in the function NoNullString, and I am looking for a way to quickly jump out of the function in order to see what the caller was and improve the code.

F5 does not do the job.

Does anybody have any ideas? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to see call stack. From there you can navigate through the stack.

You can then use `Set Next Statement` (<kbd>CTRL+F9</kbd>) on the `End Function` of your errored function. Two times <kbd>F10</kbd> to complete execution of this function. Repeat this step till you are in the scope where you think the error originated. Then, if you are on x86 (so you have `Edit&Continue` available), fix your code, and drag your currently executed line to the moment when this fix would occur. And then try running your function again.

Unfortunately, you cannot `Set Next Statement` outside of the current block function/sub, which I was going to suggest originally.

Comment: Note that this depends on your settings. If you use the C# (?) keyboard mappings, it's `CTRL + D`, `CTRL + C` (for `D`ebug, `C`allstack)